# Creating a unique Id and saving it in DB

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring REST. I have to achieve the below mentioned requirement using Spring REST. I have to use JPA Repository for DB interaction

I have 2 tables, Application and App_Config. Application table has the following rows:

id(Primary Key), ApplicationId, Status, Source_System. App_config table has the following rows: ApplicationId (foreign key), HeaderText, FooterText. I need to use java UUID to generate a unique id for the application every time a new application sends an HTTP POST request. Based on the ApplicationId generated I need to save the data in App_Config table. There is a possibility that the same application appears twice. In that case I have to retrieve the already generated ApplicationId and load the Header and Footer from App_Config table.
Please advise how to achieve this via POST method. I need to send back only the generated ApplicationId to the user

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution of your problem (the other part is not understood) regarding sending a rest with UUID and the rest api will be server+/generator/uuid

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.UUID;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/generator")
public class UuidGeneratorRestController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/uuid", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<UUID> getUUID() {
    UUID generated = UUID.randomUUID();
    return new ResponseEntity(generated, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

}

Comment: Hey, "There is a possibility that the same application appears twice. In that case I have to retrieve the already generated ApplicationId and load the Header and Footer from App_Config table."

If it is trying to modify a persisted object then I am assuming 'PUT' request is to be sent, but in that case the put request will take the object id as the key to find and update the object. 

But you are saying object need to look for other items first to see if those things exist or not, it is slightly confusing to me.

Comment: Thankfully I got a solution to the above problem! Apologies for not being able to explain the doubt clearly